# My question is how to place yellow tab based on PDF field names

Tags: java, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am working on creating a generic microservice that takes a PDF and send to multiple signers via email for signature.

I am trying to place yellow box(tab) on PDF fields where signer needs to sign. It seems there are 3 ways of doing that:

1. `x, y` coordinates(not suitable for the project, since it won't be easy to ask calling program to measure PDFs to provide that)
2. `anchorString`, not ideal since editing on PDF is not suggested
3. `CompositeTemplate` seems the only way to go. not sure what is done wrong, that yellow tab just won't show.

   ```
       byte[] buffer = readFile( docPdf);
       String docBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(buffer);

       // Create the DocuSign document object
       Document document = new Document();
       document.setDocumentBase64(docBase64);
       document.setName(docPdf); 
       // can be different from actual file name
       document.setFileExtension("pdf");
       document.setTransformPdfFields("true");
       // many different document types are accepted
       document.setDocumentId("1"); 
       // a label used to reference the doc


       ArrayList<CompositeTemplate> compList = new ArrayList<CompositeTemplate>();
       CompositeTemplate compoTemplate = new CompositeTemplate();

          //Add to Composite template
       compoTemplate.setDocument(document);

       //Create Envelope recipients, including them in the first template
       ArrayList<Signer> signers= new ArrayList<Signer>();

       Signer signer1 = new Signer ();
       signer1.setEmail("***@***");
       signer1.setName("Jane Doe");
       signer1.setRecipientId("1");
       signer1.setRoleName("Test");
       signer1.setRoutingOrder("1");


       SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere();
       signHere1.setTabLabel("aaa");
       signHere1.setRecipientId("1");
       signHere1.setDocumentId("1");
       signHere1.setPageNumber("6");

       Tabs recipientTabs = new Tabs();
       recipientTabs.setSignHereTabs(Arrays.asList(signHere1));

       signer1.setTabs(recipientTabs);

       signers.add(signer1);

       Recipients recipientList = new Recipients();
       recipientList.signers(signers);

       //Create the list for InlineTemplates


       ArrayList<InlineTemplate> inlineTemplateList = new ArrayList<InlineTemplate>();
       InlineTemplate inlineTemplate = new InlineTemplate();
       inlineTemplate.setSequence ( "1");
       inlineTemplate.setRecipients(recipientList);

       inlineTemplateList.add(inlineTemplate);

       //Create the composite template, inline template lists.
       compoTemplate.setCompositeTemplateId("1");
       //compoTemplate.ServerTemplates = templateList;
       compoTemplate.setInlineTemplates(inlineTemplateList);

       //Take the Composite Template list, add both 

       compList.add(compoTemplate);

       //Create the definition for the envelope
       EnvelopeDefinition  envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
       //Add the Composite Template list
      // envelopeDefinition.setCompositeTemplates(templateList);
       envelopeDefinition.setEmailSubject("composite ***** ");
       envelopeDefinition.setCompositeTemplates(Arrays.asList(compoTemplate));
     //  envelopeDefinition.setRecipients(recipientList);

       envelopeDefinition.setStatus("sent"); // requests that the envelope be created and sent.
   ```

Comment: June, are you using the nodeJS client (npm package). This may be an older version.

Answer (score 0):

see this note in the document about tabs (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/tabs):

Important: The names of the PDF fields must match the (case-sensitive) tabLabel values of the DocuSign tabs you wish to transfer values to. If the PDF field names match the DocuSign tabLabel, you can set the transformPdfFields property to true for a given document in the documents array like this.

(I don't see the tabLabel property in your code)